# settings in slack that gives you access to the bot [Zapier]

Tags: bots, integration, slack, zapier

I am new to Zapier. There is some steps in Zap that integrates it with Slack. When someone pushes files from Slack, Slack Bot sends message like "XYZ files have been successfully uploaded to Encompass" but actually the files are not getting uploaded in Encompass.

I am wondering if the Slack Bot sends message but why files are not getting uploaded in Encompass.
Could somebody helps me with this issue? Do I need to do anything in Slack setting to make that work?
But I am not able to see settings in Slack, I can see just Administration.

[image]

Thank you in advance! I would really appreciate the help!
I am in need to fix it immediately.